# how can i take an input with a textbox1 // use a for loop to count till 50 // and output it in textbox2

Tags: javascript, input, textbox, output

i got a textbox id="t1" that takes one input
lets say the input is: 20

i use a nother textbox id="t2" for the output which shoold look like this:
21
22
23
24
25 
...
49
50
1 
2
3
4
5
...
max lenght of the "numbers" = 50 with a break after every number 
i did the following code::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function add()
  {
    var a = document.getElementById("t1").value;
    for(i = a; i<51; i++) {
      a+=i +"<br>";
  }
  document.getElementsByName("t4")[0].value= a;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <input class="t1" type="number" id="t1">
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <br><br>
  <input style="height: 500px;" class="t2" type="textbox" name="t4"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

which rly don't work like I want, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `<input type="textbox">`, use `<textarea>` tag for multyline textbox.
If you need 50 numbers, you have to iterate 50 times.
And you need some logic to start over when number reaches 50.

Run the snippet below:

```js
function add() {
  var v = +document.getElementById("t1").value;
  var a = [v * (v < 50) + 1];
  for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) a.push(a[i] + 1 - 50 * (a[i] > 49));
  document.getElementsByName("t4")[0].value = a.join('\n');
}
```

```html
<input class="t1" type="number" id="t1" value="50">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<br><br>
<textarea style="height: 200px;" class="t2" name="t4"></textarea>
```

Comment: omg, you got me whole step to my goal !!! ty very much
edit: is there a way to get 1 instead of 51 , when i give in 50 as input? bec. 
he goes 50 as input, and 51 2 3... as output
its rly not necessary, but would help me alot : ) ty anyway !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the second textbox to 'textarea' and use '\n' instead of `<br/ >`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function add()
  {
    var a = document.getElementById("t1").value;
    for(i = a; i<51; i++) {
      a += i + "\n";
  }
  document.getElementsByName("t4")[0].value = a;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <input class="t1" type="number" id="t1">
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <br><br>
  <textarea style="height: 500px;" class="t2" type="textbox" name="t4"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```